# Command lnd not found even after installing lnd

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ubuntu, bash

I tried installing lnd using the commands shown in the [installation guide](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md).
I used these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
cd lnd
make install
```

but when I try running the lnd command, I get this:

```
Command 'lnd' not found
```

I have go1.18.1 installed. I did execute these commands, but nothing changed:

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Here are the `$GOPATH` and `$PATH` variables:

```
echo $GOPATH 
/usr/local/go
```

```
echo $PATH
/home/ayoub/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ayoub/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

How can I solve this issue?
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

edit: Here is the output of `sudo make install`:

```
go install -v -tags="" -ldflags " -s -w -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.Commit=v0.14.3-beta -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.CommitHash=bd0c46b4fcb027af1915bd67a3da70e8ca5c6efe -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.GoVersion=go1.18.1 -X github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/build.RawTags=" github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/cmd/lnd
```

Comment: 1) What was the output from `make install` - were there any error messages?  2) you must have done something in between `export GOPATH=~/go` and `echo $GOPATH` to get `/usr/local/go` instead of `/home/ayoub/go` - what did you do exactly? 3) What is the output of `type go`?

Comment: 1) I added the output in the question
2) I had `GOPATH` written in my `~/.bashrc`, but even after removing it and re running the `export GOPATH=~/go` command nothing changed
3) the output of `type go` is `go is /usr/local/go/bin/go`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `/usr/local/go/bin` is in your path, that is probably where you should have `go` install the programs it compiles. However it isn't clear how you have `go` set up. Normally the go language tools would be kept separate from the go programs you compile and install.

Nevertheless, if the `make` command didn't emit error messages, go has compiled lnd and installed it somewhere (usually based on whatever value you had assigned to $GOPATH at that time).

I would find lnd using the following commands  ...

```
find /home/ayoub -name lnd
find /usr/local -name lnd
```

and then `mv` it to `/usr/local/go/bin/lnd`

I would also check ownership and permissions.